# My <div> is bigger than my <body>

Tags: html, css

When I set my  width to 100% and my `<body>` width to 900px.

This is what I get:

```
    ___________
   _|my body  |_
  |_ My div    _|
    |my body  |
    |         |
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What is the point of doing that?

Comment: I think the point is to have it scrolled, so that based upon some sort of state on the page, the div would show different parts of itself...

Comment: From the picture it looks like you want something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/ha7fK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this similar to what you are trying to accomplish?

http://jsfiddle.net/ha7fK/1/

I changed the width to 300px for the demo at jsfiddle. Just change `300px` to `900px`

HTML

```
 <body>
  <div class="width900">
   Width of 900px
  </div>

  <div class="widthfull">
      <div class="text">
        Width of 100%
      </div>    
  </div>

  <div class="width900">
   Width of 900px
  </div>
</body>​
```

CSS

```
 body {width:100%;}
.width900 {width:300px; background:#ccc; margin:auto;}
.widthfull {width:100%; background:#eee; margin:auto;}
.widthfull .text {width:300px; margin:auto;}
```

​